# A second-order recursion (functional equation)

Tags: random-matrices, functional-equations

In a calculation of some momenta of random matrices (GOE), I encounter a functional equation, in the form of a second-order recursion,
$$L(s+1)=L(s)+2s(2s+1)L(s-1).$$
Is it familiar to someone ? Is there an explicit formula for the solutions ? By explicit, I mean in terms of the Gamma function for instance.

Just in case, I am interested in the solution generated by $L(0)=1$ and $L(1)=-\frac18$ .

Comment: @ChristianRemling Oups ! I fix it. Actually, it is $L(s-1)$ instead of $L(s+1)$ in the RHS.

Comment: This should succumb pretty easily to generating functions; you can get the $2s(2s+1)L(s-1)$ term by doing the usual differentiation (see e.g. section 2.4 of https://www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/docs/math/2011-228/mit-ocw-generating-func.pdf ). This'll give you a second-order ODE for $\mathcal{L}(x)=\sum_nL(n)x^n$ that you may have more luck finding.

Comment: FWIW Mathematica gives $$L(s)=2^{s-3}\left(\left(\frac{17}{\sqrt{2}}-9\right)\Gamma\left(s+1\right)+\frac{17(-1)^s}{\sqrt{\pi}(s+1)}\Gamma\left(s+\frac{3}{2}\right){}_2F_1\left(1,s+\frac{3}{2};s+2;-1\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already pointed out by @KStarGamer in the comment above, Mathematica can sum the recursion using `RSolve[]`. The result can be rewritten in terms of the [regularized incomplete Euler beta function $I_x(a,b)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) and reads, for arbitrary $L_0=L(0)$ and $L_1=L(1)$,
\begin{align}
\tag{1a}\label{eq:1a}
L(s)
&= 2^s s!\left[\frac{2 L_0-L_1}{\sqrt{2}}
\big(1 - I_{-1}\left(s+1,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\big)
-L_0 + L_1\right] \\
\tag{1b}\label{eq:1b}
&= 2^s s!\left[\frac{2 L_0-L_1}{\sqrt{2}}
I_{2}\left(\tfrac{1}{2},s+1\right)
-L_0 + L_1\right]
\end{align}
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function),

> The regularized incomplete beta function is the cumulative distribution function of the beta distribution, and is related to the cumulative distribution function $F(k;n,p)$ of a random variable $X$ following a binomial distribution with probability of single success $p$ and number of Bernoulli trials $n$:
> $$F(k;\,n,p)=\Pr \left(X\leq k\right)=I_{1-p}(n-k,k+1)=1-I_{p}(k+1,n-k).$$

This might link to the OP's original problem.

Comment: I apologize that I never learnt softwares such a Mathematica. I should have, but I grew up in the prehistoric times (without personal computers). Thanks a lot !